# Can I estimate the probability of an inventory dropping below a given level in the future based on historical inventory levels?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am looking for advice on how to solve the following:

- I know my current inventory, and I have monthly data on historical inventory level
- Inventory levels do not have a clear upward/downward trend, but fluctuate quite significantly
- I want to forecast the likelihood of inventory dropping below a given level over a ten year span (to inform a liquidation decision)
- My initial thinking was to look at variance and use this information to create a confidence interval under the normal distribution, but my understanding is that this is flawed since each month of inventory is independent

Ultimately, I am looking to be able to say: we have 100 inventory units today - if we liquidate 20 of them, there is a ~5% chance we will be short within a year, ~6% chance we will be short within 2 years, etc.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Seems like a Math problem in the field of Statistics, which I am ignorant of.  Is this problem of interest to you as a Math problem assigned from a book or class, or because this is a real world problem that you have to solve for your business?  Related - have you ever taken a course in Statistics?

Comment: I have taken stats, but many moons ago. This is a real-world problem to help a family member.